# Стилизация номеров строк (цифр) в списках ol(li)

Tags: html, css

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: myCounter;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

li:before {
  counter-increment: myCounter;
  content: counter(myCounter);
  color: #f60;
}
```

```html
<ol start="3">
  <li> Посадить дерево </li>
  <li> Построить дом </li>
  <li> Вырастить сына </li>
  <li> Накопать картошки </li>
  <li> Вырастить дочь </li>
  </ol
```

Как изменить цвет у чисел списка?
Проблема в том, что если добавить counter, то новый список нумеруется начиная с 1, а это не нужно.

Answer (score 3):

**Первый вариант:**

```css
.list {
  counter-reset: li+2;
  list-style: none;
}

.list li:before {
  content: counter(li);
  counter-increment: li;
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ol class="list">
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
  <li>Dolor</li>
  <li>Sit</li>
  <li>Amet</li>
  <ol>
```

**Второй вариант:**

```css
.list {
  color: red;
}

.list span {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ol class="list" start="3">
  <li><span>Lorem</span></li>
  <li><span>Ipsum</span></li>
  <li><span>Dolor</span></li>
  <li><span>Sit</span></li>
  <li><span>Amet</span></li>
  <ol>
```

Comment: почему `<a>` а не   `<span>`  ?

Comment: @Air, а чем хуже `<a>`?:)

Comment: @Air, убрал, дабы глаза не мозолило))

Comment: Вопервых там `a` не нужет вообще, как и другой тег...   а во вторых `a` ссылка так используй как ссылку)))

Comment: @Air, привык использовать в `<li>` > `<a>`, из-за навигационных меню, уж простите за косяк))

Comment: Спасибо St1myL. Работает и стилизуется, но есть одна небольшая проблема - вы значение переменной start вынесли в стили, а мне оно нужно на странице(оно будет генериться - каждый раз разное)

Comment: @MyNick, есть еще вариант со `span`. Слова в `li` оборачиваете в `span`, затем даёте `span`'y `color: #000`, а списку даёте допустим `color: red`

Comment: @St1myL Хорошо бы точку и пробел добавить, а то как-то режет глаз `1. Lorem`

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, решил вторым вариантом